# UIImage initWithData behaves differently on iOS 4.3

Tags: ios, ios4

I have an app that's been running fine in the App Store for 6 months or so, but none of its images (downloaded from a web site via "NSURLConnection initWithRequest") show up in iOS 4.3. It turns out that I have a line of code that looks like this:

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

and shortly thereafter, to get ready for the next image, I do this:

```
data.length = 0;
```

When I comment out setting the length to zero (deferring it until the download of the next image begins), it works on iOS 4.3.

I've checked carefully to make sure there's no buffer interference, but each of my images is in its own instance of an object that has the buffer (data) as an instance variable.

It seems to me that in iOS 4.3 the initWithData implementation is not completely finished with the data when the method returns. Perhaps some work is being deferred until the UIImage is assigned to the UIImageView, which happens a bit later? Maybe even deferred until the UIImage is rendered?

Can anyone shed light on this seemingly-new behavior in iOS 4.3?

Comment: Hey Marc I have same issue. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I think  your analysis sounds about right. It's easy to imagine the kind of small change that would cause this, for example UIImage may have been changed to retain the data rather than copy it, or something like that. I'd file a bug with Apple to make sure that someone notices the issue, and then work around it by changing your code to:

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[[data copy] autorelease]];
```

At least, I assume that'd work around it. It'd be very interesting if it doesn't... please let us know one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks, Caleb... I don't want the overhead of a copy, and I don't need it, since each UIImage has a dedicated buffer. I want that buffer released when the UIImage is fully baked, though. So, I release the buffer as soon as the call to initWithData returns, and just avoid setting its length to zero. This seems to work reliably, adding credence to the theory that the UIImage is retaining it as long as it needs it.

Comment: I think you're doing roughly the same thing, then. Previously, you must have been using a single instance of NSMutableData (since you were able to set its size to 0) and re-using it for each image. Copying would create an immutable version of that, and let you continue to use the same NSMutableData to load the data. Your way works fine too, and as you say, without the copy. Glad you got it sorted.